# How to show configurable product attributes on homepage

Tags: magento-1.7, configurable-product

I just want to display all products with the attribute options on homepage whatever available but mainly color attribute. I was able to get for the simple product but when it comes with the configurable product it doesn't show anything.

The option is displaying on the product page but how can I make it happen on homepage.

Comment: This is not possible out of the box. I think there is a lot of javascript and phtml to implement to have this. I'm sure the JS is not yet possible to handle more than one product on the page and the second problem is, that it will be resource intensive to generate all the selects and JS...

Comment: Show us template that you use on home page, and CMS page content :)

Comment: Show us template that you use on home page, and CMS page content :) by @kuba-ceg

Comment: Sorry for not responding soon but i got the solution.
Thanks for your replies guys.

Comment: Please add the answer to your question!

Comment: @Waseem can u please share the code?i m also stuck with that issue.

thanks in advance.